# Centered page numbers with headers in memoir class

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I am in hurry and I really need to know how to style the page in `memoir` class. All the examples in page style such as Rule,empty, headings and Plain doesn't give the combination I need. Plain styles is the closest as it give bottom centered page numbers but without headers. I need both headers and page numbers at bottom centered on every page.

Can anybody please give me solution?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very plain template to set *all* the headers and footer in [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir). It's taken almost verbatim from the [`memoir` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) (section **7.3 MAKING HEADERS AND FOOTERS**):

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makepagestyle{hurried}% Create hurried page style
\makeevenfoot{hurried}% Adjust even footer for hurried page style
  {LEF}% Left even footer
  {CEF}% Center even footer
  {REF}% Right even footer
\makeevenhead{hurried}% Adjust even header for hurried page style
  {LEH}% Left even header
  {CEH}% Center even header
  {REH}% Right even header
\makeoddfoot{hurried}% Adjust odd footer for hurried page style
  {LOF}% Left odd footer
  {COF}% Center odd footer
  {ROF}% Right odd footer
\makeoddhead{hurried}% Adjust odd header for hurried page style
  {LOH}% Left odd header
  {COH}% Center odd header
  {ROH}% Right odd header
\makeheadrule{hurried}{\textwidth}{.4pt}% Header rule width/thickness for hurried page style
\makefootrule{hurried}{\textwidth}{.4pt}{\footruleskip}% Footer rule width/thickness/skip for hurried page style

\pagestyle{hurried}% Set page style to hurried

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{A chapter}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-10]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[1-10]
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

If you don't want to be as extravagant and set *everything*, you can `\copypagestyle` from an existing one (like `Ruled`, `ruled`, `plain`, ... any of the ones mentioned in section **7.2 PAGE STYLES**).

Note that first pages of chapters in `memoir` are set in the `chapter` page style. `chapter` is not a true page style, but rather an alias for `plain`. If you wish to change that, first `\copypagestyle{chapter}{plain}`, making `chapter` a true page style, then use the above techniques. For example, to get the page number in the center of the first chapter page, use

```
\copypagestyle{chapter}{plain}% Copy plain page syle to chapter page style
\makeoddfoot{chapter}% Adjust odd footer for chapter page style
  {}% Left odd footer
  {\thepage}% Center odd footer
  {}% Right odd footer
```

Comment: Thanks Werner. I could get the page numbers at center bottom using above technique but my header is not coming up now. I am using \chapterstyle{veelo} and it has fist page number on right bottom. Don't know how to fix that. 

Also what should I use for {LOH} to get the header as chapter title?

thanks very much for help.

Comment: @user51906: I've added what you need for the chapter first page. The chapter title will be stored in `\leftmark`, so you could use `\makeoddhead{hurried}{\leftmark}{?}{?}`.

Comment: Hi Werner, that did fix the first page number to center. But I still don't get the headers right. So this is what I have in preamble

Comment: \chapterstyle{veelo}

\usepackage[left=4cm,right=3cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\copypagestyle{chapter}{plain}
\makeoddfoot{chapter} {}{\thepage}{}
  \makepagestyle{hurried}
  \makeevenfoot{hurried}{}{\thepage}{}
  \makeevenhead{hurried}{\leftmark}{}{}
  \makeoddfoot{hurried}{}{\thepage}{}
  \makeoddhead{hurried}{\leftmark}{}{}
\pagestyle{hurried}% Set page style to hurried

Comment: and I have a thesis.tex that has the structure like this 

\documentclass[ 12pt, a4paper, oneside]{memoir}
%\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, draft]{memoir}
\input{preamble}
\begin{document}
 \frontmatter
%  \maketitle

  \tableofcontents

  \listoffigures

  \listoftables
 \mainmatter

%  \include{./chapters/intro}              
%  \include{./chapters/methods}        
%  \include{./chapters/results1}                 
  \include{./chapters/conclusions}     
%  \include{./chapters/appendices}
% \include{./chapters/supplementary}
 \backmatter
  \bibliography{references}
\end{document}

Comment: @user51906: You mention that you "still don't get the headers right", but I don't see any obvious problem with the code snippets. What is not right about it?

Comment: I get the the header on every page but it is same throughout the document and does not change with different chapter title. Its not even taking the chapter title but appears as 'List of Table' as header on every page!

Comment: I tried your solution on a separate file and everything works as expected. What I think is \leftmark doesn't recognise my chapter titles somehow and takes \listoftables as headers or whichever is available.
Do you think it won't be able to take chapter title through \include{./chapters/intro} ?

at least page number works fine.
thanks.

Comment: @user51906: No. Are you using some chapter titling package (like [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)) or some other document class (like [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir))? If it works on a separate file and not on your thesis, then you're doing something different.

Comment: Using \rightmark worked fine for me and its all good now! Thanks very much for your help